# error api Post con nodejs express y MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, express

Hola estoy realizando una pequeña una pequeña api (crud), tengo un problema con el post, me envía a la ruta,le envío datos con postman, me asegure de ocupar el conntent-type y el application/json, el tema llega la petición post al servidor, pero lo que le envío aparece como undefine, al momento de crear el objeto en este caso userData, me crea el objeto, pero su contenido esta vacío, alguien me podría orientar? ya que estoy recién viendo este lenguaje.

otra acotación, al momento de sacarle los comentarios en el código, me realiza el insert, pero los campos username, password y email los ingresa vacíos, creo que el problema esta ahí.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
//entender peticiones post
const bodyParser = require ('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');

//configuracion del servidor
//pregunto si hay un puerto definido 0 le paso el 3000
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
//obtengo el puerto y muestro el mensaje del servidor 
app.listen(app.get('port'), ()=>{
    console.log('servidor on');
    
});
//routes
require('./routes/userRoutes')(app);

//middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

```js
*/
// recivo el objeto (app) que ya esta definido 

const User = require('../model/user');


module.exports = function (app) {

    app.get('/users', (req,res) =>{
        User.getUsers((err,data)=>{
            res.json(data);
        });
    }); 

 
    app.post('/users', (req,res)=>{
    
      const  userData = {
      username: req.body
            }
        console.log(userData);
        
       
    });
}




       /* const userData = {
            
            id : null,
            username : req.body.username,
            email : req.body.email,
            password: req.body.password,
            created_at : null,
            update_at : null
            };   

*/
    /* User.insertUser(userData, (err,data)=>{
            if (data && data.insertId) {
                res.json({
                    success: true,
                    msg: 'usuario insertado',
                    data: data
                })
                
            }else{
                res.status(500).json({
                    success:false,
                    msg: 'Error'
                });
            }
        }); */
```

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');

connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'testapimysql'
});

let userModel= {};

userModel.getUsers = (callback) =>{
    if (connection){
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id', 
        (err,rows) =>{
            if (err) {
                throw err; 
            }else{
                callback( null, rows);
            }
        }
        )
    }
};

  /*  userModel.insertUser = (userData, callback) =>{
        if (connection) {
            connection.query(
                'INSERT INTO users SET ?', userData,
                (err, result) => {
                    if(err){
                        throw err;
                    }else{
                        callback(null,{ 'InsertId' : result.insertId})
                    }
                }
            )
            
        }

    };

*/
    

module.exports = userModel;
```

Comment: ¿Has hecho un `console.log(req.body)`? ¿Cómo le estás pasando los datos desde Postman? Deberías enviarlos en el `body`, como `x-www-form-urlencoded`. Verifica eso.

Comment: hola si, le hice un console.log(req.body) de echo esta en el código puesto, en el postman lo envie como x-www-form-urlencoded y application/json y me aparece esto en la consola { username: undefined } , me llega la petición post a la ruta, pero no los valores.

Comment: Debes mover los `middlewares` antes de declarar tus rutas, eso es lo que me parece que está sucediendo.  Ubícalos justo debajo de donde declaras  el puerto. Prueba eso y me comentas

Comment: Otra cosa, tus rutas debes declararlas antes de levantar el servidor. Mueve la linea de `app.listen(...)` al final de tu archivo.

Comment: muchas gracias, me funciono :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Aplicación Express no recibe datos cuando se realiza una solicitud `POST`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

El problema está en la forma en que realizas la configuración de la aplicación Express. Tienes declarados tus `middleware` al final, incluso tus rutas están después de levantar el servidor.

Uno de los errores más comunes es declarar las rutas y los `middleware` después de levantar el servidor.

Una forma correcta de configurar una aplicación ExpressJS es la siguiente:

1.- Se realiza la importación o requerimiento del módulo `express`

```
//ES6
import express from 'express';

//ES5
const express = require('express');
```

2.- Se incializa la variable (usaremos `app` como ejemplo)

```
const app = express();
```

3.- Se pasan las funciones middleware a nuestra app

```
app.use(helmet()); // middleware que configura las cabeceras HTTP (debe estar previamente importado con import o require según sea el caso)
app.use(express.json()); // he visto que mucha gente usa bodyParser
                         // sin embargo, si se usa la versión 4.16.x de Express, no es necesario instalar bodyParser
                         // ya que viene instalado como dependencia de Express.
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
})); // otro middleware para trabajar con la codificación del objeto body. Tampoco es necesario usar bodyParser si se usa la versión 4.16.x de Express.
```

4.- Se pasan las rutas a nuestra aplicación

```
app.use('/', routes(router)) // hay muchas formas de hacerlo, en este ejemplo se usa un middleware
                             // llamado 'routes' al cual se le pasa un objeto router, ambos deben estar
                             // previamente declarados o importados, segun sea el caso
```

5.- Se levanta o inicia el servidor

```
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Servidor escuchando...');
});
```

Este debe ser el orden aproximado, cada aplicación cambia. Pero normalmente mantienen este orden: app -> middleware -> rutas -> listen

Espero que tu problema se resuelva de esta manera.

Saludos